# Document.createNodeIterator() - prevent infinite iteration

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to mark a case insensitive word in **DOM**. For example, I want to mark **stackoverflow** with `<mark>stackoverflow</mark>` and `Google` with `<mark>Google</mark>`

To do so, I am using  `Document.createNodeIterator()` that filters all none text nodes.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  getChildren(document.body);
}

function getChildren(mytag) {

  const nodeIter = document.createNodeIterator(
    mytag,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
    (node) => {
      return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT
    }
  );
  const mark = document.createElement("mark")
  let node = nodeIter.nextNode();
  while (node) {
    const parent = node.parentElement;
    const innerHTML = parent.innerHTML;
    const word = "stackoverflow"
    const regex = new RegExp(`(${word})`, 'ig');
    parent.removeChild(node)
    parent.innerHTML = innerHTML.replace(regex, "<mark>$1</mark>");
    node = nodeIter.nextNode()
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Iterating DOM in JavaScript</h1>

<p>
  A paragraph.
</p>

<div>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow</a> is QA website.
</div>

<ul>
  <li>Stackoverflow</li>
  <li>Google</li>
  <li>Apple</li>
</ul>
```

The code above does not work. It itrerates infinitely. However, if I replace the word that matches with another word, for instance `stackoverflow` with `<mark>duckduckgo</mark>`, it does not iterate infinitely.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that when you replace the node, the node iterator goes through the same content over and over again forever.

You can improve two things:

1. The filtering logic can be done as part of the filter callback. So, you can reject any nodes you do not want right there, instead of getting text nodes and examining them.
2. Use [`Node#replaceWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith) to change the node. I have used it with [`Node#cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) to construct the replacement but you can also use other ways to do it. `replaceWith()` does accept a DOMString, if that is what you prefer.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  getChildren(document.body);
}

function getChildren(mytag) {
  const word = "stackoverflow"
  const regex = new RegExp(`(${word})`, 'ig');
  
  const nodeIter = document.createNodeIterator(
    mytag,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
    (node) => {
      //ignore script and style tags
      if (node.parent?.tagName === "SCRIPT" || node.parent?.tagName === "STYLE")
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
        
      //ignore anything already marked
      if (node.parent?.tagName === "MARK")
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
        
      //ignore anything not matching regex
      if (!regex.test(node.data))
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
        
      return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    }
  );
  let node = nodeIter.nextNode();
  while (node) {
    const parent = node.parentElement;
    const mark = document.createElement("mark");
    mark.append(node.cloneNode());
    
    node.replaceWith(mark);
    node = nodeIter.nextNode()
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Iterating DOM in JavaScript</h1>

<p>
  A paragraph.
</p>

<div>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow</a> is QA website.
</div>

<ul>
  <li>Stackoverflow</li>
  <li>Google</li>
  <li>Apple</li>
</ul>
```

And here is the code tidied up which might help with readability:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  getChildren(document.body);
}

function getChildren(mytag) {
  const nodeIter = unmarkedTextIterator(mytag, /stackoverflow/ig);
  
  for (const node of iterate(nodeIter)) {
    node.replaceWith(mark(node));
  }
}


//helper functions to break up the logic into logical parts:


/*
 * Create a DOM NodeIterator for text nodes only. 
 * @param {Node} root - where to start.
 * @param {RegExp} regex - optional filter for what text to watch. Defaults to returning everyting.
 * @return text node which is not in <mark> or <script> or <style> tag and passes the regex filter.
 */
const unmarkedTextIterator = (root, regex = /.*/) =>
  document.createNodeIterator(
    root,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
    (node) => {
      //ignore script and style tags
      if (node.parent?.tagName === "SCRIPT" || node.parent?.tagName === "STYLE")
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
        
      //ignore anything already marked
      if (node.parent?.tagName === "MARK")
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
        
      //ignore anything not matching regex
      if (!regex.test(node.data))
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
        
      return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    }
  );

/* 
 * Convenience generator function to easily work with NodeIterors
 * @generator
 * @param {NodeIterator} nodeIterator
 * @yields {Node} that nodeIterator gives
 */
function* iterate(nodeIterator) {
  while (node = nodeIterator.nextNode()) {
    yield node;
  }
}

/* 
 * Wraps a node in <mark> tag
 * @param {Node} node
 * @return {Node}
 */
const mark = node => {
  const mark = document.createElement("mark");
  mark.append(node.cloneNode());
  
  return mark;
}
```

```html
<h1>Iterating DOM in JavaScript</h1>

<p>
  A paragraph.
</p>

<div>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow</a> is QA website.
</div>

<ul>
  <li>Stackoverflow</li>
  <li>Google</li>
  <li>Apple</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. But my bad. I have not specified all cases. I might have `<li> Stackoverflow is a QA website</li>` where I want to mark only Stackoverflow.

Comment: This works for the two cases that I havce specified in my question.